# this err ValidationError: email: Path `email` is required. Node.js

Tags: node.js, postman, validationerror

I am currently programming with Node.js and I am trying to make the password reset route.
But when I try in Postman I get an error in my Terminal:

```
this err ValidationError: email: Path `email` is required.
```

I am shure the error is in this method:

```
function(token, done) {
  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email },
    function(err, user) {
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        error: "User not found"
      });
    }
    console.log('step 1')
    user.resetPasswordtoken = token;
    user.resetPasswordExpires = Date.now() + 3600000; // 1 hour
    console.log('step 2')
    user.save(function(err) {          
      done(err, token, user);
    });
  });
}
```

To be more precise I am sure it is in the part.

```
 user.save(function(err) {          
          done(err, token, user);
        });
```

Here is my User schema

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    email: { 
        type: String, 
        required: true, 
        unique: true, 
        match: /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/
    },
    firstname: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    lastname: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
         type: String, 
         required: true 
        },
    resetPasswordtoken: { 
        type: String, 
        required: false
    },
    resetPasswordExpires: { 
        type: Date,
        required: false
        }
});
```

Thank you for your help.

Here is the beginning of the method

```
router.post('/forgot', (req, res, next) => {
  User.find({ email: req.body.email })
  .exec()
  .then(user => {
    async.waterfall([
      function(done) {
        crypto.randomBytes(20, function(err, buf) {
          var token = buf.toString('hex');
          done(err, token);
        });
      },
      function(token, done) {
        //User.findOne({ email: req.body.email },
          //function(err, user) {
        if (!user) {
          return res.status(404).json({
            error: "User not found"
            });
          }
          //}
          console.log('step 1a')
          console.log(req.body.email)
          user.resetPasswordtoken = token;
          user.resetPasswordExpires = Date.now() + 3600000; // 1 hour
          console.log('step 2b')
          user.save(function(err) {          
            done(err, token, user);
          });
```

Comment: As your model suggest, the email is required . Usually this error occurs when you are not passing the required data to the server. Try to console.log the req.body.email and tell us what you get.

Comment: I get undefined

Comment: Ok that means that means you didn't pass the email value in req.body correctly. Can I see your axios or fetch request?

Comment: Do you mean the Postmenrequest?
If yes then: localhost:4563/forgot as an post request and the body:
{
 "email": "nikolai@tom.de"
}

Comment: I mean the code where you did the axios or fetch request .

Comment: I edditet it. See above